# Convert RGB to YCbCr - C code

Tags: c, opencv, rgb

I need to convert RGB to YCbCr for my final project and I trying to do this way (I'm programming in C):

```
/* Autor: Vinicius Garcia
 * Data : 09.ago.2011
 * 
 * Função que converte um pixel RGB em YCbCr
 * 
 * param : int R valor do pixel no canal red
 * param : int G valor do pixel no canal green
 * param : int B valor do pixel no canal blue
 * return: int* vetor de inteiros com os valores H, S e V calculados - nesta ordem
 */
int* converter_RGB_para_YCbCr(int R, int G, int B){
    int* YCbCr = (int*) malloc(3 * sizeof(int));

    double delta = 128.0; //Constante necessaria para o calculo da conversão de cor
    double Y  = (0.299 * R + 0.587 * G + 0.114 * B);
    double Cb = ((B - Y) * 0.564 + delta);
    double Cr = ((R - Y) * 0.713 + delta);

    YCbCr[0] = (int) Y;
    YCbCr[1] = (int) Cb;
    YCbCr[2] = (int) Cr;
    return YCbCr;
}
```

But it doesn't work for me!

I was comparing with cvCvtColor (from OpenCv library) and the results doesn't match:

```
            R = 88,  G  = 76,   B = 78
cvCvtColor: Y = 80,  Cb = 127, Cr = 134
myfunction: Y = 382, Cb = 132, Cr = 132 (cr and cr are always equal!)
```

I really need help with this, I trying do this for a long time and I couldn't find any answer for my doubt.

---

Do you guys think I'm getting the RGB values wrong? I'm doing this way:

```
uchar B = CV_IMAGE_ELEM(img_RGB, uchar, linha, coluna * 3);
uchar G = CV_IMAGE_ELEM(img_RGB, uchar, linha, coluna * 3 + 1);
uchar R = CV_IMAGE_ELEM(img_RGB, uchar, linha, coluna * 3 + 2);
```

Then I'm calling my conversion function this way:

```
converter_RGB_para_YCbCr(R, G, B);
```

My function expects int R, int G, int B but I'm passing uchar B, uchar G, uchar R. its that ok?

Comment: Hmm, that is Odd; even doing it by hand and using your method, Y = 80 (or rather rounded to 80 when converted to int)

Can you inspect your method at the point where you assign Y,Cb and Cr to your YCbCr return value, and post what the values are here ?

Comment: Also what is this delta for ? I've not seen that used myself. Ill post an answer with the conversion as I'm aware of it...

Comment: No idea where you get Y = 382, it can never be > 255, assuming that R, G and B can be maximum 255. I get Y = 79.816, using a "pocket" calculator.

Comment: Same here Rudy, I wonder if it's type conversion ?

Comment: Running this code, I get: y=79, cb=126, cr=133.  How are you printing these?

Comment: Here is a very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973115/opencv-convert-rgb-to-ycbcr-and-vice-versa-by-hand-visual-c

Comment: I think the bug is in your printing code... (not in the posted code).

Comment: Nothing wrong with the function: http://ideone.com/KzRUt. Either your input data or printing function is amiss.

Comment: Certainly the print or the cast ... tricky :)

Comment: Try printing `R`, `G`, and `B` at the start of `converter_RGB_para_YCbCr`, and your calculated `Y`, `Cb` and `Cr` values before exiting.  @R.. is probably correct -- it's an error in how you're passing data to the function, or what you're doing with the result.  Post the code that follows the function call, showing how you're printing the results.

Answer (score 7):

```
int y  = (int)( 0.299   * R + 0.587   * G + 0.114   * B);
int cb = (int)(-0.16874 * R - 0.33126 * G + 0.50000 * B);
int cr = (int)( 0.50000 * R - 0.41869 * G - 0.08131 * B);
```

Comment: Hey guys! thanks for your help!
the 'delta' I took from cvCvtColor manual 
http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=cvcvtcolor#cvCvtColor
It is used for 8-bit images.

Comment: thanks Russ.
but I had try this code too but I got the same problem. =(

Comment: Cr gives me a negative value (-127.5), shouldn't we be adding 128 to that value?

Comment: Hi Dominicbri7; I have seen an implementation that does indeed add 128 to the sum for cb and cr actually.

Answer (score 3):

you should use this formula matlab uses it

Y = 0.257R´ + 0.504G´ + 0.098B´ + 16

Cb = -0.148R´ - 0.291G´ + 0.439B´ + 128

Cr = 0.439R´ - 0.368G´ - 0.071B´ + 128

and to rgb

R´ = 1.164(Y - 16) + 1.596(Cr - 128)

G´ = 1.164(Y - 16) - 0.813(Cr - 128) - 
0.392(Cb - 128)

B´ = 1.164(Y - 16) + 2.017(Cb - 128)

I have tested them in a software im making they work ok